# Is there any tool for manupolation Json data?

Tags: json

I have a large Json log file which contain result of a web service call. now I need to search inside it and find some element with multiple condition.

is there any tool for making query and administration On json log file?

Comment: you can use a programming language you are familiar with

Comment: Have a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). You can also try it online at https://jqplay.org/.

Comment: I am familiar with some of theme such as C#, PHP but i preferred use a thridy party tool.

Comment: I try it but its online demo is not enough power full for my huge log file an also i did n't find any Documentation about query on json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the file in an editor to understand its structure. If the file is huge, as you write, browse it page-by-page with a command such as *more* or *less*.

Then use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to obtain the data that interests you. Start by extracting some top-level elements to get the hang of the process and then gradually refine your invocation to what you actually want to obtain.

The [jq tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) has many invocation examples. You can also see a specific use case in a [blog post](https://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20171117/) I wrote on recovering Firefox session data from the browser's json session file.